# Get file content from multipart format

Tags: java, file-upload, io, inputstream, multipartform-data

What I wanna do here is user uploads his file and I will store this file into my server side

IMPORTANT: I can ONLY use "servlet-api.jar(2.4 version)", I cannot use other JAR!

I use `<form action=\"/Mapreduce/upload\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">` to upload my file.

Then I use this code `InputStream whole = request.getInputStream();` to get the whole inputstream.

Then I use this code to get the string of the file content

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whole, "UTF-8"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);// sb is stringbuilder here
}
```

Then, I convert the string I get from stringbuilder to InputStream:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("UTF-8""));
```

Finally, I write this `InputStream is` to another file(temp) by using the following code:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(temp);// temp is a file.
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
```

When I upload the .txt file, it works and I can open the temp.txt. However, when I upload the .docx file, I cannot open the temp.docx. How can I solve this problem? Is it because my encoding is wrong?

Comment: What you using , it is servlet upload file or Webservice upload file. why you need to encode file even you are using multipart. you can upload file directly without encoding

Comment: @Raju Sharma, it is servlet upload file. Actually, what I wanna do here is user uploads his file and I will store this file into my server side

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to do that much of thing. you can do it like below:

index.html

```
<html>  
<body>  
<form action="go" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  //here go is path for servelet
Select File:<input type="file" name="fname"/><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="upload"/>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

UploadServlet.java

```
import java.io.*;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  
import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;  

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {  

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
    throws ServletException, IOException {  

response.setContentType("text/html");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"d:/new");  //d is directory to upload file
out.print("successfully uploaded");  
}  
}
```

web.xml file

```
<web-app>  

<servlet>  
<servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>UploadServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/go</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

and download the cos.jar file from the link: http://ftp.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcosmultipartjar.htm. and put it to you classpath.

Comment: sorry, I can ONLY use "servlet-api.jar(2.4 version)", I cannot use other JAR!

Comment: i dont think the servlet-api.jar file supports different encoded file (like doc,docx) data to be uploaded, you need to upload file using some external jar only. Similarly if you read file using java then java can only read .txt file not others like : doc,docx,pdf. we need to use external jars to read these files.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your Servlet code as,

```
Part filepart=request.getPart("file");
    System.out.println(filepart);
    String filename=null;
    if(filepart!=null){
        System.out.println("IF filepart not null");
        System.out.println(filepart.getName());
        System.out.println(filepart.getContentType());
        System.out.println(filepart.getSize());
        System.out.println(filepart.getInputStream());


               String contentDisp = filepart.getHeader("content-disposition");
               System.out.println("content-disposition header= "+contentDisp);
               String[] tokens = contentDisp.split(";");
              for (String token : tokens) {
                if (token.trim().startsWith("filename")) 
                System.out.println(token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length()-1));
            filename=token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length()-1);
            System.out.println("File Name New is: " +filename);            
    }           

    }   

    InputStream inputstream=null;
    if(filepart!=null)
    {
        inputstream=filepart.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("File data: " +inputstream);
    }
```

Here you get file name and contents of uploaded file, After this code you can write code for storing file in DB or on your system.

Comment: @sorry, I can ONLY use "servlet-api.jar(2.4 version)", I cannot use other JAR! `Part` is 3.0 version feature!

Comment: @CSnerd How it possible then to upload files without jars. Atleast you need commans-fileupload.jar and commans-io.jar with their respective versions.

Comment: Use form the below guy provided `<form action="go" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select File:<input type="file" name="fname"/><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="upload"/>`